# Web API not recognizing new users when created by Web Portal

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

I have a Web API and an Azure Web App that access the same database. This database has all user information. I'm using ASP.NET Identity for user management. I'm having an issue where when a user is created by the web app the Web API requires a restart, or at least a relatively long while before the user becomes authenticated by it. This, of course, is entirely impractical. How can I update the environment immediately on the Web API so that the user can access their resources?

**UPDATE 3:**

Turns out it WAS authenticating with the API, but I didn't hold the correct claims because my user was not associated with a Google account. See Answer below.

Comment: Please show how you are configuring ASP.NET Identity for both sites.  I do this and have no issues,

Comment: @BrendanGreen That's a lot of code. What specifically would you like to see? Just the IdentityConfig.cs for each?

Comment: Yes - identity config for both,

Comment: That is code for the manager.  How are you configuring the OWIN middleware?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to. Where would I find that in the project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94875/discussion-between-lavahot-and-brendan-green).

Comment: I updated my question with the configuration I think you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. Nevermind. We require Google accounts to sign on one kind of client, and we SHOULD require it on the web client, but I haven't set that up yet. If an account is set up without an associated Google account, AND that email has a Google account set up on the client then it will try to authenticate with those Google claims that don't exist in the DB. So while I CAN authenticate with that claim through the Google SSO, there are no claims set up in the DB, resulting in 401 errors. Authenticated, but unauthorized.

This means my auth filter is probably misconfigured because it should not authenticate with Google if my account does not have an associated Google account, no matter what my client requests. It also means that I need to refactor my SPA on my Web App that statically calls for Google authentication with the API.